# How to extract parent and child node information with multiple children to a dataframe, using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have the following XML:

```
<households>
    <household id="4">
        <members>
            <personId refId="9"/>
            <personId refId="10"/>
            <personId refId="11"/>
        </members>
        <income currency="CHF" period="month">
                4000.0
        </income>
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="bikeAvailability" class="java.lang.String" >FOR_SOME</attribute>
        </attributes> 

    </household>
    <household id="13">
        <members>
            <personId refId="40"/>
            <personId refId="42"/>
        </members>
        <income currency="CHF" period="month">
                18000.0
        </income>
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="bikeAvailability" class="java.lang.String" >FOR_ALL</attribute>
        </attributes>
    </household>
</households>
```

I want to create a data frame which has 3 columns; household id | person id | income

Therefore I want to extract `household id`, all the `personId refId` and eventually the `income`. So ideally my output would look for this example like that:

```
householdId personId    income
4           9           4000.0
4           10          4000.0
4           11          4000.0
13          40          18000.0
13          42          18000.0
```

This is my code so far, together with the syntax error

```
import pandas as pd
import gzip
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(gzip.open(hhzip, "r"), 'xml')  #xml_txt is your XML text from the question

css_selector = ','.join('household > members > personId')

data = {'personId':[], 'income':[], 'householdId':[]}
for person in soup.select(css_selector):
    data['personId'].append( person['refId'] )
    data['income'].append( person.find_parent('household').find('income').get_text(strip=True) )
    data['householdId'].append( person.find_parent('household')['id'])


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("hh_income.csv", sep=';')

SelectorSyntaxError: The combinator ',' at postion 19, must have a selector before it
  line 1:
h,o,u,s,e,h,o,l,d, ,>, ,m,e,m,b,e,r,s, ,>, ,p,e,r,s,o,n,I,d
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script to get the information:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_txt, 'xml')  #xml_txt is your XML text from the question

data = {'household': [], 'personId':[], 'income':[]}
for household in soup.select('household'):
    for person in household.select('personId'):
        data['household'].append(household['id'])
        data['personId'].append( person['refId'] )
        data['income'].append( household.find('income').get_text(strip=True) )

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  household personId   income
0         4        9   4000.0
1         4       10   4000.0
2         4       11   4000.0
3        13       40  18000.0
4        13       42  18000.0
```